# How to stop search after finding the first desired character and copy the rest text?

Tags: python, regex

I've a string having `CUSTOMER_SEGMENT_PRIV` and want to get an output of `CUSTOMER_SEGMENT equal to PRIV`

```
>>> re.sub('_{1}',' ot lauqe ','CUSTOMER_SEGMENT_PRIV'[::-1])[::-1]
'CUSTOMER equal to SEGMENT equal to PRIV'
>>> re.sub('((?:_[^_\r\n]*){1})$',' ot lauqe ','CUSTOMER_SEGMENT_PRIV'[::-1])[::-1]
'CUSTOMER equal to SEGMENT equal to PRIV'
```

What I want:

```
'CUSTOMER_SEGMENT equal to PRIV'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A shorter way using a good regex :

```
>>> import re
>>> re.sub( r'_([^_\r\n]*)$', ' equal to \\1', 'CUSTOMER_SEGMENT_PRIV' )
'CUSTOMER_SEGMENT equal to PRIV'
```

Comment: it works, thanks! Can you please explain how \\1 can be used in replacement? Is it part of re.sub or regex itself? Thanks in advance!

Comment: In Python, the capture variables are referenced in the replacement string as _backslash_ plus capture number. In this case the backslash has to be escaped for the language parser, i.e. `'\\1'`. In some other languages, the capture groups can be referenced within the replacement string with a dollar sign as well, i.e. `'$1'`

Answer (score 1):

No need to use regex, just use [`str.rsplit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rsplit) with `maxsplit=1` and `str.join`:

```
>>> s = 'CUSTOMER_SEGMENT_PRIV'
>>> x = s.rsplit('_', 1)
>>> x
['CUSTOMER_SEGMENT', 'PRIV']
>>> ' equal to '.join(x)
'CUSTOMER_SEGMENT equal to PRIV'
```